# Beautiful Soup - handling errors

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

1. I'd like to know how to handle a situation when `href` doesn't exist after the `<strong>Text:</strong>`
2. Is there a better way to search for the content that exists after `<strong>Contact:</strong>`

http://pastebin.com/FYMxTJkf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [findNext](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Searching%20Within%20the%20Parse%20Tree)?

```
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<strong>Text:</strong>   

        <a href='http://domain.com'>url</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
label = soup.find("strong" , text='Text:')
contact = label.findNext('a')

if contact.get('href') != None:
    print contact
else:
    print "No href"
```

If you're looking specifically for an `a` tag with an `href`, use:

```
contact = label.findNext('a', attrs={'href' : True})
```

With this you won't need to condense whitespace. I imagine you did this because `next` was returning the whitespace after the label.